# SSRS User Defined Functions

Tags: reporting-services, user-defined-functions

Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way, but in order to keep the code in my .rdl files to a minimum I would like to use a user defined function in order to populate the value in a placeholder. The UDF will just return a string. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a table valued function:

select ColumnName from dbo.udfName(ParameterValues)

for a scalar valued function:

select dbo.udfName(ParameterValues)